# RAMDISK data transfers in C (fread)

Tags: c, opencl, ramdisk

Right, so I'm trying to optimize a software that needs to read a huge image file (1.3 GB) in C/OpenCL in order to transfer it to the device by 40 MB blocks.

I created a RAMDISK with tmpfs to store the file but when I analyze bitrates I find that using a RAMDISK is actually a bit slower than using my SSD to read the image file.

So I'm wondering, does the open operation (using fopen) do a RAM-to-RAM transfer to store data in the buffer ? Or is it the filesystem's overhead that causes this performance issue ?

Comment: If I understand correctly tmpfs may use swap space.  This may be slowing something down.

Comment: I have the same bitrates using a ramfs file system that can't use swap.

Comment: Use of `fopen()/fread()` results in the data being copied three times on its way to your code's buffers:  disk->page cache->FILE buffer->code buffer.  If you're doing a pure streaming read, that's useless.  Just use `open()/read()` and use direct IO. (O_DIRECT `open()` flag on Linux.)  Also be sure to `memset()` your buffer before you read into it as it may not have a physical page yet.

Comment: So I tried what you proposed :
`int input = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY|O_DIRECT);`
But `open()` keeps returning -1, even if I specify a mode like 0777.

Comment: Check `errno` for the real error. `O_DIRECT` is not guaranteed to be supported.

Comment: Actually, `O_DIRECT` with a file on my ext4 partition works but it's not available on a tmpfs/ramfs file system. Or at least by default ? Is there a way to make that work ?